# want java class object to have optimize memory utilization

Tags: java, memory, optimization

i have a class defined as:

```
public class Percolation{
    private boolean[] openCells;
    private WeightedQuickUnionUF uob;
    public Percolation(int n){
        this.openCells = new boolean[n*n+1];
        this.uob = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(n*n+1);
}
```

on calling Percolation(n), both WeightedQuickUnionUF object and openCells[] take O(n^2) space.

now interesting thing is that i if have to call Percolation(n), for some certain no of times (say t), i dont need to call the constructor Percolation(n), 't' times, i can overwrite once i have allocated memory for n.
but for that i can find two solutions:

1.to release memory used by the constructor once i hv done the required operations and then again call Percolation, but going through some odr StackOverflow threads made me realize that it wont ensure memory release, and wold depend on garbage collector.

2.i can add a method, (shown at bottom) in class percolation to overwrite the members of class WeightedQuickUnionUF, but the problem is that all the members of WQF are private.

3.i can add a method in class WeightedQuickUnionUF, to overwrite the members of class, but WeightedQuickUnionUF is read only.

```
private void set_containers(n){
        for(int i=0; i<n*n+1 ; i++){
            this.openCells[i] = false;
            this.uob.id[i] = i;
            this.uob.sz[i] = 1;
        }
```

i dont have much experience in java, and need to know how i can optimize memory utilisation in such cases.

full code:

> http://ideone.com/Hnorn8
>
> http://ideone.com/h3uL0a

thank u :)

Comment: I would suggest using a `BitSet` rather than `boolean[]`.

Comment: @ELP thanx for inputs, as i said that i am new at java and didnt know of bitset, i require to overwrite the members of a contructor, or find a way to free the memory used by it, would bitset do that?

Comment: Without looking at the complete code, I'm blind here. If you need this variables only for few operations, you shouldn't define these as instance variables but instead local variables in the particular function, where you need them.

Comment: I don't know what 'overwrite the members of a constructor' means, but you can clear a `BitSet.` It's a much more space-efficient representation.

Comment: @prabhjot i need to do exaclty what u say, my oops concepts are weak, your point made me think that i should make members of the class static can i do better?

Comment: It all depends on your use case. If this function is going to be called by other classes and doesn't depend on state of the current class, you can make it static. Normally, static is the last choice because it's difficult to mock static and dependency is not very clear by using static functions. You can consider it making public/private member function too.